# Loading data to use in UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView and I am populating it with image data. This data is loaded fine, but when the records increase in number (e.g. more than 50) the app starts to have problems like freezes and more. I understood that this is the line in my cellForRowAtIndexPath that is causing the issue:

```
NSData* data = [DKStoreManager loadFileWithName:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forFolderNumber:[_FolderCode intValue] forUser:[_PassedUserID intValue] andType:_FolderType];
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

I understood it because when I loaded the data only once in the viewDidLoad an used myDictionary as a global variable, then all the cells where logically be the same, but the table scrolled fine fine and the app doesn't crash. finalArray is an array with the names of the files ordered in alphabetical order and the number of rows corresponds to its count. Can anyone suggest a way to load  this data outside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method? How do I then pass everything on to the cellForRowAtIndexPath if all of the NSData are different?

What I have tried to do:

1) I tried to subclass the UITableViewCells and load the data from a method:

```
cell.FileName = [finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.PassedUserID = _PassedUserID;
cell.FolderCode = _FolderCode;
cell.FolderType = _FolderType;

    [cell loadContents];
```

I made sure using a BOOL that loadContents runs only once in the subclass. When I scroll down or up, cells change position. Its a mess...

2) I noticed that if I remove the
    if (cell == nil) {
and stop reusing the cell, there are no issues with the cells changing place, but there are huge loading time issues

2) Moving everything in the  if (cell == nil) { method, the cells still change place on scroll but the scroll is faster...

4) Loading all the data in the viewDidLoad displaying a "loading..." but the loading is really slow, it doesn't really work out.

5) Using dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ on the data load, but doesn't work, the table scrolls really slow...

PS ,myDictionary contains the image and the name of the cell.

EDIT:

All the data is saved locally, the method "loadFileWithName" loads a saved file in the documents directory.

Comment: Does `myDictionary` contain the actual image or the path to the image?

Comment: Do you have a sample project with just this part that isn't working?

Comment: its more like issue with the way you are structuring your code. Sample Project will help us to diagnose issue.

Comment: If loading all data at 'viewDidLoad' take that much time the problem is probably that the data you are loading is too "heavy", and loading one file at every 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' is still probably too slow for the scroll to be smooth. You can try to load data asynchronously in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' so that the cells will appear (empty) immediately and their content will be filled as soon as the hardware can.

Comment: myDictionary contains the actual image under a key as well as other information under other keys.

Comment: Do you really need to load all the data to tableView cells? I mean if not you can use a load more tableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see example of lazy-loading table below.

This example provides a table view with infinite number of cells; data for each cell is loaded in a background thread only when all of the following conditions are true:

- UITableView requests that cell;
- Cell that data is requested for is visible;
- UITableView is not scrolling OR scrolling is not decelerated (i.e. scrolling is performed while user’s finger touches the screen).

That is, excessive load of the system during fast scrolling is eliminated, and data is loaded only for cells that user really needs to see.

In this example, time-consuming and thread-blocking data loading operation is emulated for each cell with sleeping a background thread for 0.2 seconds. To use this example in your real application please do the following:

- Replace implementations of the `tableElementPlaceholder` getter;
- In the `performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:` method, replace the following line with your actual loading cell data:

> `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2]; // emulation of time-consuming and thread-blocking operation`
>
> Tune implementation of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method for your cells implementation.
>
> Please note that any object data needed in the loading code should be thread-safe since loading is performed in non-main thread (i.e. *`atomic`* properties and probably `NSLock` should be used inside the `performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:` method in your time-consuming thread blocking code replacing the `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2]` call).

You can download the full Xcode project from [here](https://github.com/nikolay-mamaev/iOSLazyLoadTable).

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

static const NSUInteger kTableSizeIncrement = 20;

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* tableData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id tableElementPlaceholder;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* tableDataLoadDelayTimer;

- (void)fetchTableCellDataForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
- (void)performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:(NSArray*)indexPaths;
- (void)tableDataLoadDelayTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:kTableSizeIncrement];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < kTableSizeIncrement; i++) {
        [self.tableData addObject:self.tableElementPlaceholder];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (id)tableElementPlaceholder
{
    return @"";
}

- (void)fetchTableCellDataForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (self.tableView.decelerating && !self.tableView.tracking) {
        if (self.tableDataLoadDelayTimer != nil) {
            [self.tableDataLoadDelayTimer invalidate];
        }

        self.tableDataLoadDelayTimer =
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(tableDataLoadDelayTimerFired:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
    } else {
        [self performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    }
}

- (void)tableDataLoadDelayTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [self.tableDataLoadDelayTimer invalidate];
    self.tableDataLoadDelayTimer = nil;

    NSArray* indexPathsForVisibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    [self performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:indexPathsForVisibleRows];
}

- (void)performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:(NSArray*)indexPaths
{
    for (NSIndexPath* indexPath in indexPaths) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];  // emulation of time-consuming and thread-blocking operation
            NSString* value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text at cell #%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.tableData[indexPath.row] = value;
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            });
        });
    }
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource protocol
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tableData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == (self.tableData.count - 1)) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            [self.tableData addObject:self.tableElementPlaceholder];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString* text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (text.length == 0) {
        cell.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
        [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
        cell.label.hidden = YES;
        [self fetchTableCellDataForIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        cell.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        cell.label.hidden = NO;
        cell.label.text = text;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

@end
```

For your project, the `performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:` method would look as follows:

```
- (void)performActualFetchTableCellDataForIndexPaths:(NSArray*)indexPaths
{
    for (NSIndexPath* indexPath in indexPaths) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSData* data = [DKStoreManager loadFileWithName:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forFolderNumber:[self.FolderCode intValue] forUser:[self.PassedUserID intValue] andType:self.FolderType];
            NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.tableData[indexPath.row] = myDictionary;
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Please note that you'll need to use **atomic** properties `self.FolderCode` and `self.PassedUserID` instead of instance variables `_FolderCode` and `_PassedUserID`, because loading file is performed in a separate thread and you need to make this data thread-safe.

As for the `tableElementPlaceholder` method, it might look as follows:

```
- (id)tableElementPlaceholder
{
    return [NSNull null];
}
```

Correspondingly, in the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method check if data load completed would look like this:

```
NSObject* data = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (data == [NSNull null]) {
    cell.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    cell.label.hidden = YES;
    [self fetchTableCellDataForIndexPath:indexPath];
} else if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
    [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    cell.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
    NSData* actualData = (NSData*)data;
    // Initialize your cell with actualData...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way not to call [self fetchTableCellDataForIndexPath:indexPath]; when the user is scrolling fast not to overload the system? I tried by calculating scroll velocity but what happens is that if the user stops the scrolling with his finger, then the cells remain empty...

Comment: @Alessandro, the solution here is to defer loading data for cells until scrolling completes. This can be done with a timer which fires when table view stops repeated requests for cells. I've updated my answer and the [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/nikolay-mamaev/iOSLazyLoadTable) with this solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean in the source code for replace sleep(2) with time consuming...?

Comment: For your case, replace `sleep(2)` with 2 lines of code: 

`NSData* data = [DKStoreManager loadFileWithName:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forFolderNumber:[self.FolderCode intValue] forUser:[self.PassedUserID intValue] andType:self.FolderType];


NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];`

Comment: Thanks, the method is very effective. Sure there is no way to load the data when the scrolling is slow?

Comment: Nikolay thanks, this was quite what I was looking for. I appreciated the sample code. @3r1d I'm really sorry, your method worked great, I have implemented it, but I found Nikolay's one fitted in better. I wish I could +400 both of you...

Comment: @Alessando, I've improved background data loading; now data load is deferred only if scrolling is not decelerated. Unfortunately I couldn't implement recognition of case when scrolling is slow but decelerated. Please see updated answer and [GitHub example project](https://github.com/nikolay-mamaev/iOSLazyLoadTable/releases/tag/IOS_LAZY_LOAD_TABLE_0.3). Thank you for the bounty!

Answer (score 3):

## Not a good idea

Loading a lot of cells on a `tableView` it's not a good way to display data. Let suppose if a user wants to take a look at your data, he will take a look at your first elements (suppose max 20 cells), why he should drag to see elements all the way down? If he wants more he just goes down and clicks load more. User doesn't want to keep waiting and loading all the data to the memory (RAM).

## Suggestion

For me the best way is to add a **load more function** (also called **infinite scrolling**) when you go to the bottom of your loaded elements (it's the same way as pagination on websites).

## Implementation

There is a great library to achieve this thing called [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh). This library allow you by draging down the tableView to trigger a method (**completionHandler**) where you should load more data at the end of tableView.

```
//This is where we add infinite scrolling to the tableView
__weak YourViewController *weakSelf = self;
[self.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
        [weakSelf loadMoreData];
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

Now that we added load more, we need to setup our data. First we declare a `NSInteger *lastIndex;` as an instance variable, an inthe `viewWillAppear` we instantiate it with 0, and call loadMoreData which will give the lastIndex the value 20

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    lastIndex = 0;
    [self loadMoreData];
}
```

This is the method that takes care of data from Array to tableView. Here we are describing an example which gets 20 elements for load more pressed.

```
-(void)loadMoreData {
    //Lets suppose we are loading 20 elemets each time

    //Here we control if we have elements on array
    if(yourDataArray.count - lastIndex>0) {
        //We control if we have 20 or more so we could load all 20 elements
        if(yourDataArray.count - lastIndex>=20) {
            lastIndex += 20;
        } else {
            //Our last index is the last element on array
            lastIndex = yourDataArray.count - lastIndex;
        }
    } else {
        //We have loaded all the elements on the array so alert the user
    }
}
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` we return the lastIndex

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return lastIndex;
}
```

## Conclusions

To deal with images you should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) as the other answers suggested. Dealing the problem of scrolling this way, you eleminate the way to add large amount of data on tableViews at the first look at it. Maybe it's not the right answer to deal with your idea (if you really need to load all data to your tableView), but it tells you how to avoid loading data at giving you performance at scrolling to your tableView.

*p.s I am using this example in my Social Networking App and it's working great. (Also Instagram, Facebook and other apps are dealing with loading data this way).*

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar approaches as yours in the past years and they all have been wrong. If I were you I would use 2 different approaches:

1) If you load images from a remote server use a great library called `SDWebImage` or write your one of own. It's going to get as simple as just `[self.imgViewBack setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data.eventImageURL];`

2) You could also save all your images to `NSDocumentDirectory` and while them stored there - just use an `NSDictionary` of paths.

My general recommendation here goes as follows - never create an array or dictionary of raw data of objects the size more than a few kilobytes. This will result in terrible freezes and memory waste all over the place. Always use paths to the object and store them somewhere else - and you will benefit.

Generally `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is the most frequently used in `UITableViewDataSource` protocol so it should be executed with lightning fast speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store everything locally and not on a server as SergiusGee said, I would suggest keeping, for example, only 50 images in memory.

There's the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, where you could control which elements are loaded.

For example, when displaying the 50th cell, you have images between index 30-70. After every 10th cell, you could unload the unneeded ones and reload new ones to keep a `[x-20, x+30]` range, where x is the current cell.

Obviously this will take quite some effort to implement, but loading everything and keeping it in memory is certainly not the answer.

Also, the numbers are just for the examples sake.

Comment: Great suggestion but I assume that sometimes the laziest implementation with a few lines of code is the best working one. Writing your own logics for reusing cells is just the thing that is implemented in `UITableView` by default.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a theoretical suggestion. Though UITableView only implements the logic of reusing cells, not the data source as well. My logic is referring to the reuse of the data source.

Comment: The cellForRowAtIndexPath only loads the current visible cells, so what you are suggesting is to load more to either side of the ones which are visible than what the cellForRowAtIndexPath would do?

Comment: No, as far as I've understood, his problem was with the loading of the data and keeping too much of it in memory. I might have misunderstood the question then.

Answer (score -1):

Do not load the data from file in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Try loading them into an array of `UIImage` in `-viewDidLoad:` synchronously or async-ly (which is up to you) because it does not take too much time for `UIImage` to be presented but it is **extremely expensive** to load raw data to construct an `UIImage`.

Comment: This is a pretty terrible recommendation because you are now preloading tons of stuff into memory at startup..