# Updating UITableView: inserting a row

Tags: ios

I am inserting inserting some rows into my UITableView in the following way:

```
__weak OpenFolderViewController *weakSelf = self;

NSMutableArray* arr = [[DKStoreManager getFileNameListForUser:[_PassedUserID intValue] andFolderCode:[_FolderCode intValue] andType:_FolderType ordered:@"ALPHABET"] mutableCopy];
[arr removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(20, arr.count - 20)];
[arr removeObjectsInArray:itemArray];
NSLog(@"%@", arr);

int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
    [itemArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
    //[itemArray addObject:@"FrateNote1692890348.txt"];
    [weakSelf.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:itemArray.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];

    [weakSelf.tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating];
});
```

The array "are" contains the right objects, including FrateNote1692890348.txt, however if I use:

```
[itemArray addObject:@"FrateNote1692890348.txt"];
```

in the update method the app works ok and the row is added, while if I use:

```
[itemArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
```

the app crashes with error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3185.20/UITableView.m:1487
```

on line

```
[weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: It seems that you are adding more objects versus the number of row you are adding

Comment: You can ask me at your question about this, why is a need that you should ask another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190413/loading-data-to-use-in-uitableview-cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: @3r1d are you sure you read both of the questions? They look quite different to me...

Comment: @3r1d oh sorry, I didn't see that you where the same person